# What does rawValue 1 of attitudeReferenceFrame mean?

Tags: ios, swift, gyroscope

I am trying to find out the reference frame of the CMMotionManager I am using to track gyro data.  When I execute the following lines

```
let referenceFrame = self.motionManager.attitudeReferenceFrame
print("Reference frame = \(referenceFrame)")
```

I get the following output

```
Reference frame = CMAttitudeReferenceFrame(rawValue: 1)
```

There are 4 constant for CMAttitudeReferenceFrame

> Constants
>
> static var xArbitraryZVertical: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame Describes a
>   reference frame in which the Z axis is vertical and the X axis points
>   in an arbitrary direction in the horizontal plane.
>
> static var xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame
>   Describes the same reference frame as xArbitraryZVertical except that
>   the magnetometer, when available and calibrated, is used to improve
>   long-term yaw accuracy. Using this constant instead of
>   xArbitraryZVertical results in increased CPU usage.
>
> static var xMagneticNorthZVertical: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame Describes
>   a reference frame in which the Z axis is vertical and the X axis
>   points toward magnetic north. Note that using this reference frame may
>   require device movement to calibrate the magnetometer.
>
> static var xTrueNorthZVertical: CMAttitudeReferenceFrame Describes a
>   reference frame in which the Z axis is vertical and the X axis points
>   toward true north. Note that using this reference frame may require
>   device movement to calibrate the magnetometer. It also requires the
>   location to be available in order to calculate the difference between
>   magnetic and true north.

Is it talking about the second constant by rawValue of 1?

Comment: You are right. It is `xArbitraryCorrectedZVertical`.

Comment: Raw value 1 is `xArbitraryZVertical`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coremotion/cmattitudereferenceframe/cmattitudereferenceframexarbitrarycorrectedzvertical?language=objc) say that the second one of those has value `1 << 1` (that is, 1), so yes.

Comment: `1 << 1` is 2, `1 << 0` is 1